# what's the best way to add increment decrement function

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, increment

I'm trying to build an app to move stocks around. I have products and storages. I want to be able to move X count of products from storage A to storage B. I guess I need some credit/withdraw function to update increment quantity on one side and decrement on the other side.

What would be your approach with Rails? I need to figure out the middleman too that will handle all transactions as I'm not sure with Db relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ActiveRecord::Transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html)